# Let $f(x)=30-2 x-x^{2}$ and $f_{n}$

Tags: functions, inequality

> Let $f(x)=30-2 x-x^{2}$ and $f_{n}(x)=\underbrace{f \circ f \circ \cdots \circ  f}_\text{$n$ times}$. Then, find the number of positive integral values of $x$ which satisfy $f_{2014}(x)$ < $f_{2013}(-x)$.

The answer is $2$.

My doubt is should the question have given $x^3$ instead of $x^2$? Else the given question is not monotonic? So how should one proceed.

Comment: I rather suspect that the less-than sign is the wrong way

Answer (score 0):

As $f(x)=29-(x+1)^2$, we see that $f$ is strictly increasing on $(-\infty,-1]$. 
Also, 
$$f(x)-x=(4-x)(7+x)<0$$
and hence $$f(x)< x\qquad \text{for }x<-7.$$ 
Then $f_n$ maps $(-\infty,-7]$ strictly increasingly to itself. 
Thus if $x$ is a positive integer with $$\tag1f(x)<-x\le -7,$$ then by applying $f_{2013}$ on both sides, we get $$\tag2f_{2014}(x)<f_{2013}(-x),$$ as desired.
More generally, if instead of $(1)$, we have
$$\tag3 f_{k+1}(x)<f_k(-x)\le -7$$
for some integer $0\le k\le 2013$, then by applying $f_{2013-k}$ to both sides, we also arrive at $(2)$.

As
$$f(x)+x=\frac{113}4-(x+\tfrac12)^2<0\qquad\text{for }x\ge5, $$
we see that $(1)$ ans therefore $(2)$ holds at least for all integers $x\ge 7$.

For $x=6$, we have $f(x)=-20$ and hence certainly $f_{2014}(x)<-7$, whereas $f(-x)=4$ and therefore (as $f(4)=4$) $f_{2013}(-x)=4$. So $(2)$ holds here.

For $x=5$, we have $f(x)=-7$ and hence $f_{2014}(x)=-7$, whereas $-5\mapsto 13\mapsto -167$ and hence $f_{2013}(-x)<-7$ and $(2)$ does not hold.

For $x=4$, we find $f(x)=4$ and hence $f_{2014}(x)=4$, whereas $f(-4)=20$, $f(20)=-412<-7$ and hence $f_{2013}(-x)<-7$ and $(2)$ does not hold.

For $x=3$, we find $3\mapsto 13\mapsto-167\mapsto -27527$, whereas $-3\mapsto 25\mapsto -647$.
For $x=2$, we find $2\mapsto20\mapsto-412\mapsto-168892$, whereas $-2\mapsto 28\mapsto -812$.
For $x=1$, we find $1\mapsto 25\mapsto -647\mapsto -417287$ whereas $-1\mapsto 29\mapsto -871$. Hence in these three cases, $(3)$ holds with $k=2$ and therefore $(2)$ holds.

**Conclusion.** 
$$f_{2014}(x)<f_{2013}(-x)$$
holds for every $x\in\Bbb Z_{>0}\setminus\{4,5\}$.

Comment: f(x) = 31 - (x+1)^2 instead of 29-(x+1)^2 in first line.

Comment: There is calculation mistake in first line.

Comment: Does this help : $f-{n+1}(x)=31-(1+f_n(x))^2, f_0(x)=x$ ?

Comment: This will not solve.